# Will reclustering a table change the Micropartitions in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Will reclustering a table change the micropartions in Snowflake? I remember reading somewhere that Micro-partitions can not be changed once created and are immutable. I am obviously mixing different things. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you enable clustering on a table, the data will be re-distributed to the micro-partitions in background by the clustering service. It will sort data (time to time) and create new micro-partitions, delete the old ones.

This article may be helpful:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-auto-reclustering.html

Comment: Siddhant, You are correct that they are immutable, btw.  That is why any change to the data creates new micropartitions, including clustering.